# Jquery function in document.ready inserting twice as page is paginated

Tags: jquery

I have some code that is wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function()` I am using the `insertAfter()` method and the page is paginated so when I scroll to the next page the previous page gets another element inserted. Is there a way to prevent this?

**`code`**

```
$(document).ready(function()
        (ImageTop).insertAfter('#item-7');
});
```

Comment: is that all codes you have ?